# Guaranteeing enough storage space for 4*ceil(n/3), where n is an int

Tags: c, malloc, computer-science

Let's say `n` is an integer (an `int` variable in C). I need enough space for “4 times the ceiling of n divided by 3” bytes. How do I guarantee enough space for this?

Do you think `malloc(4*(int)ceil(n/3.0))` will do, or do I have to add, say, `1` in order to be absolutely safe (due to possible rounding errors)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative to KerrekSB's general formula which guarantees that only one division is used, is to calculate

(n+m-1)/m

To see that it produces the same, write `n = k*m + r` with `0 <= r < m`. Then `n%m == r`, and if `r == 0`, we have `n+m-1 = k*m + (m-1)` and `(n+m-1)/m == k`, otherwise `n+m-1 = (k+1)*m + (r-1)` and `(n+m-1)/m == k+1`.

Most modern hardware gives you the quotient (`n/m`) in one register and the remainder `(n%m)` in another when you do an integer division, so you can get both parts of Kerrek's formula in one division, and most compilers will do so. If the compiler doesn't, but uses two divisions, the calculation will be considerably slower, so if the computation is done often and performance is an issue, you can work around the compiler's weakness with somewhat less obvious code.

In the given case, the `malloc` would be

```
malloc(4*((n+2)/3));
```

But since it's not obvious to everyone what that formula does, if you use it, explain it in a comment, and if you don't need to use it, use the more obvious code.

Answer (score 5):

you can achieve the same thing with pure integer arithmetic which guarantees that you allocate the correct amount of memory:
**edit** fixed brackets

```
malloc(4*((n+2)/3))
```

Comment: Shouldn't there be an extra set of parentheses?

Comment: ups yeah I was just looking at the ceil(n/3) part while thinking about it. fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

To compute the ceiling of `n / m` integrally, just say:

```
n / m + (n % m == 0 ? 0 : 1)
```

All in all, say `malloc(4 * (n / 3 + (n % 3 ? 1 : 0)));`.

Comment: Or `(n+m-1)/m` to use only one division if the compiler isn't clever enough.

Comment: @DanielFischer What do you mean? Can you elaborate? What exactly would you put into the malloc?

Comment: @DanielFischer: Very nice! Why not post it as an answer :-)

Answer (score 1):

While Kerrek SB has a precise answer, in practice most engineers would use `malloc (4 + 4 * n / 3)` or (equivalently) `malloc (4 * (1 + n / 3))`.  The rules for `C` evaluate `n/3` as an integer resulting in truncating remainder away.  Adding a little more to the expression ensures that any fraction ignored by the division is allocated.

At most, this might waste three bytes.  Only if there are at thousands of these would any extra computation to account for that be justified—maybe.  Implementations of `malloc` often round storage allocations up to multiples of 4, 8, or 16 bytes to simplify its housekeeping.

Consider the cost of 3 bytes of memory:  [Current pricing](http://www.newegg.com/Store/SubCategory.aspx?SubCategory=147&name=Desktop-Memory) is $5 to $15 per gigabyte.  Three bytes cost $0.000 000 009.

Comment: Given that Bort's and Daniel's solutions actually produce the correct number on the nose in all cases with the same number of operations, I'd say those are preferable... memory isn't just about money, but also about cache locality and things like that.